# Cordova - iOS Bottom pixels not clickable

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a 1-page app written in cordova 8.0.0 that requires a tab-bar in the bottom of the page. Tabs should have an onclick event each that hides/shows some elements. I added the onclick like this `$( '[data-action]:not(#footer .active):not(i)' ).off().on( 'click', function() {...}` and it seems to be working fine, **except** if you click to the bottom (around 30) pixels which will not trigger the onclick for some reason.

1) I tried taking the tab-bar 30px higher and the onclick works on every pixel of the tabs.

2) I tried creating a brand new app and adding only the tabs (with the same CSS, so that I make sure that CSS was not the issue) and the onclick event to it, and it seems that it works fine all the way to the bottom, but when I copied the exact code to my current app, the issue persisted!

I tried keeping everything the same (even config.xml) but I am not sure if there is anything created during the app creation that could potentially be the cause of the issue.

This issue is totally frustrating and I know that searching for an answer here is a long shot, but I thought I should give it a chance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems. The issue was related to `cordova-plugin-googlemaps`. If you upgrade it to the last version, this should fix it.

See the following:

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1919

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/commit/d41f4362df341161a5119a46b6d979e9c2aa2e3b